# How to delete or set lifespan to zero - Dialogflow Agent Context

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to ask you how could I set to zero or null a lifespan of a context.

Example that I’ve tried:

```
    const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment'); //"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

agent.context.set({
            'name': 'context_name',
            'lifespan': 0 
          });
```

Or

```
agent.context.set({
            'name': 'context_name',
            'lifespan': null
          });
```

Or

```
agent.setContext({ name: 'context_name', lifespan: 0 });
```

Or

```
agent.setContext({ name: 'context_name', lifespan: null });
```

or

```
agent.context.delete('context_name');
```

However, it always sets itself up to the value of 5 again.

Is there a way to delete or set it to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `clearContext()`:

```
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment'); //"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

agent.clearContext('context_name');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks it does work for me. However, I found out that I can't declare an output context on Dialogflow, because if I do, this line of code won't work.

Comment: `agent.clearContext` is deprecated. Consider using `agent.context.delete('context_name')`

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear the context inside your intent handler. contexts are updated every time an intent is invoked. the preferred way to clear the context is

```
agent.context.delete('context_name');
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaannks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the lifespan to "-1" by doing the following:

```
agent.setContext({ name: 'context_name', lifespan: -1 });
```